# Aggregate One-to-Many Relationship in MongoDB with Subdocument References

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, one-to-many, aggregation-framework

Consider a document with two arrays, `lines` and `nodes` each containing many sub-documents and add'l nested documents not shown for clarity

```
{
    {"lines": [
        {
            "guid": 1
            "def": {
                "n1": 49,
                "n2": 50
            }
        },
        ...]
    },
    {"nodes": [
        {
            "guid": 49,
            "def": {
                "x": -43.9709,
                "y": 14.8688,
                "z": -121.988
            }
        },
        {
            "guid": 50,
            "def": {
                "x": -30.5955,
                "y": 29.5512,
                "z": -115.024
            }
        },
        ...]
    }
}
```

How could one query Mongo to return a restructured document of `lines`, pulling only what we need from `nodes`?

```
{
    {"lines": [
        {
            "guid": 1
            "def": {
                "n1": {
                    "guid": 49,
                    "def": {
                        "x": -43.9709,
                        "y": 14.8688,
                        "z": -121.988
                    }
                }
                "n2": {
                    "guid": 50,
                    "def": {
                        "x": -30.5955,
                        "y": 29.5512,
                        "z": -115.024
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...]
    }
}
```

Coming from a healthy understanding of RDBMS, and new to MongoDB. I've been spending a lot of time hacking away with the aggregation framework to try and achieve this, but having no luck. Is there something simple I am missing?

I expect an alternate data model might be more appropriate. The above will no doubt start to crash up against the 16 MB BSON document limit for the concerning use case.

Comment: If I understand it well, `"def": { "n1": 49, "n2": 50 }` will store references to other embedded documents. As you have here an unbound number of fields, there is probably no way to process that with the aggregation framework. Not mentioning the difficulty to perform such "self-join". Maybe using map-reduce ? Anyway, unless you have a very good reasons to stick with that data model, I would suggest to re-think your schema.

Comment: Is what you're asking is you need really to query the 'nodes' array first and filter down to only what you want that is contained within that array along with the line information.